# Finding hidden apps on home screen iPhone XR

Tags: ios

I removed a game app from my Home Screen when I wanted to delete it.  How do I get the icon back on my Home Screen?  I looked at iTunes but could not find apps there.  I removed the app on the home screen by clicking on and holding the app icon, then I hit hide app instead of delete app. I can only open app through App Store.  I have software version 14.3.  Thanks!

---

Update: I used the App Library and found the icon.  Thank you!!!

Comment: What steps did you take to remove it? Please edit that in as well as edit the question body to include the version of iOS from the general portion of the settings app. Different iOS have different app behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 14 you can find apps in the App Library if you remove the icon from Home Screen. You can also find these with Siri and Spotlight.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211345

For older iOS versions you need to reinstall the app from the source (usually the App Store).